# Trains: reusing previous task id

Tags: trains, clearml

I am using `reuse_last_task_id=True` to overwrite an existing task (with same project and task name). But the experiment contains the torch model and therefore does not overwrite the existing task but creates a new one. How can I detach the model from the task?

Answer (score 1):

Copying the answer from Trains team here.

Try to do `reuse_last_task_id=<task_id_here>` ,to specify the exact Task to continue )click on the ID button next to the task name in the UI)
If this value is true it will try to continue the last task on the current  machine (based on project/name, combination) if the task was executed on another machine, it will just start a new one

Comment: BTW: if you want to report a specific plot to an already executed Task, you can always retrive the Task object of the pre-executed experiment, get the logger of it, and report a specific missing metric)
`
Task.get_task(task_id='aabbcc').get_logger().report_scatter2d(...)
`